# Separate class for the same purpose

Tags: c#

I have this class

```
public class BlessingDTO
{
    public List<string> BlessingCategoryName;

    public List<string> Blessings;
}
```

I am Getting the response of the two lists this way:

```
public async Task<List<BlessingDTO>> GetBlessing(string UserType)
{
    string blessing = "Blessing_" + UserType;
    List<BlessingDTO> results = new List<BlessingDTO>();
    using (DTS_OnlineContext context = new DTS_OnlineContext())
    {
        var items = await context.Messages.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.MessageContext == blessing).GroupBy(x=>x.GroupKey).Select(b=>b.OrderBy(x=>x.Sort)).ToListAsync();
        if (items.Count() > 0)
        {//Notes.Select(x => x.Author).Distinct();

            results = items.ToList().ConvertAll(x => new BlessingDTO()
            { BlessingCategoryName = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageName).Distinct().ToList(),
                Blessings = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageText).ToList()
            });
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

if I am changing the class, for my porpuse to be:

```
public class BlessingDTO
{
    public List<string> BlessingCategoryName;

    public List<bless> Blessings;
}

public class bless
{
    public string text;

    public int length;
}
```

how can I initialize the new class ?

```
Blessings = new bless
```

won't give the results. how can I save the data to bring them in the response

Comment: `Blessings = new bless` does not compile at all. You need a variable name on the left side at least. You need parentheses and a semicolon on the right side.

Comment: Tip: Always use `.Any()` instead of `.Count() > 0`. `.Count()` always goes through every element in the enumerable, whereas `.Any()` stops at the first one.

Comment: Do you really need `bless.length`? I assume it will always be equal to `bless.text.Length`.

Comment: I meant how to change ` Blessings = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageText).ToList()` That will work with bless class @Dialecticus @Thomas Weller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus in this part:

```
items
    .ToList()
    .ConvertAll(x => 
        new BlessingDTO()
        {
            BlessingCategoryName = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageName).Distinct().ToList(),
            Blessings = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageText).ToList()
        }
    );
```

where `items` is probably a `List<List<Message>>`, thus `x` being a `List<Message>`.

Now what is causing an error is the following: `Blessings = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageText).ToList()`. This creates a new list for the list of messages, then selects the `MessageText` from that list, which results in `IEnumerable<string>`. In the end a new list is created for these strings. This list of strings isn't assignable to `List<bless>`, thus will generate an error.

What you want is a result of `List<bless>`, so we need to convert the `List<Message>` list into a `List<bless>` somehow. We know how to do that, namely with a select: `x.Select(message => new bless()).ToList()`. All we have to do is fill in the properties of `bless`: `x.Select(message => new bless { text = message.MessageText }).ToList()`. The other property is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the list like this:

```
public class BlessingDTO
{
    public List<string> BlessingCategoryName;
    public List<bless> Blessings = new List<bless>();
}
```

Although, I would recommend these fields are changes to properties, as that is more idiomatic in C#

```
public class BlessingDTO
{
    public List<string> BlessingCategoryName {get;set;}
    public List<bless> Blessings {get;set;} = new List<bless>();
}
```

Comment: I meant how to change 
```    Blessings = x.ToList().Select(y => y.MessageText).ToList()``
That will work with bless class